# two web service call outs from flow

Tags: webservices, visual-workflow

I need to make two web service call outs. The return of the first call is input to the second call. In my flow, I have two Apex Action elements each using its own class with @InvocableMethod annotation, however, when I run my flow the second call fails with the error message " You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out". I read that when you are in autolaunched flow, everything is DML ( I am not doing any DML with my calls, just returning value from first call as input to the service call). I cannot use future annotation since the method needs to be void. 
How can I make two calls and pass the value from the first call to the second in an autolaunched flow?

Comment: Do you need to separate the callouts? Have you tried invoking the callouts from the same method, doesn't that work?

Comment: No, that didn't work. Even making two callouts from the same method results in the same error.

Comment: Then there must be a DML which is made before the callout. Will need to see more of your code/implementation to be able to help further.

Comment: There is none. My understanding is an autolaunched flow is DML by nature. All I am doing is making a web service call, returning a value, passing the value to a second web service call. I am not storing anything in Salesforce.